# Running quick programs inside a docker container

Tags: docker

My web-application uses graphicsmagick to resize images. Resizing an image will usually take about 500ms. To simpilfy the setup and wall it off I wanted to move the `graphicsmagick` call inside a docker container and use `docker run` to execute it. However, running inside a container adds an additional ~300ms, which is not really acceptable for my use case.

To reduce the overhead of starting a container one could run an endless program (sth. like `docker run tail -f /dev/null`) and then use `docker exec` to execute the actual call to `graphicsmagick` inside the running container. However this seems like a big hack.

How would one fix this problem "correctly" with docker or is it just not the right fit here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good candidate for a microservice, a long-lived server (implemented in your language of choice) listening on a port for resizing requests that uses graphicsmagick under the hood.

#### Pros:

- Implementation details of the resizer are kept inside the container.
- Scalability - you can spin up more containers and put them behind a load balancer.

#### Cons:

- You have to implement a server

#### Pro or Con:

- You've started down the road to a microservices architecture.

Using `docker exec` may be possible, but it's really not intended to be used that way. Cut out the middleman and talk to your container directly.

Comment: I read a bit more on docker and I think this is the way to go.

I will run my whole app inside a container, as what I am building is basically a microservice for resizing images and wrapping the call to image magick in another microservice seems unnecessary. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The best ways is:

- create custom deb/rpm package
- use one from system repos

But if you like more docker approach, the best visible way is to (example below):

Start "daemon":

```
docker run --name ubuntu -d -v /path/to/host/folder:/path/to/guest/folder ubuntu:14.04 sleep infinity
```

Execute command:

```
docker exec ubuntu <any needed command>
```

Where:

"ubuntu" - name of the container

-d - de-attach container

-v - mount volume host -> container

sleep infinity - do nothing, used as entry point and is a way better than read operation.

Use mounted volume in case, if you working with files, if not - do not mount volume and just use pipes.